# How to make multi toggle work for multiple lines of nav?

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

Using this nav: http://responsivenavigation.net/examples/multi-toggle/

As you can see the sub menu drops to the edge of the bottom of the div. The problem lies in how this is handled when the page gets re-sized to a smaller width (tablet size) and the menu stacks. No matter which link you hover over, the result is that it places the sub menu below the div. Resulting in an unusable top nav. How would you go about fixing the drop down so that it can handle both lines; top and bottom?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but the UX seems to be behaving as expected to me. It works like an accordion, you can expand and collapse menu items by toggling the parent item - this is what I've seen practised on many responsive sites.

Comment: Yes but when the navigation extends to two lines, both top and bottom li open from the bottom div. The above link doesn't show it by default unless more items are added to the nav.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of a `max-height` being set on elements with `.menu` class when the `.active` class state is appended to it (Line 159 of the html file).

```
.menu.active, .menu > ul ul.active {
    max-height: 55em;
}
```

So the `nav` will not grow beyond the `max-height` value specified. To fix this, change the value to `100%` when active.

Comment: Using that method produces a drop down that is in the correct position but it extends in between the two nav bars.